# if loop shows the wrong message (sqlite python)

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

why is this if loop not working? when there is nothing in dataset, it shows the wrong message.
'''

```
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM room_data WHERE hall_name = ? and hall_number = ? and room_number = ?", (HallName.get(),HallNum.get(),RoomNum.get()))
    print('dataset:' ,cur.fetchone())
    data = cur.fetchone()


    # code below makes no sense, when data is None, message error doesnt activate

    if data == 'None':
        print('data set value is none')
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error: you can only update lease information, not room details")
        con.close()

    else:
        cur.execute("UPDATE room_data SET lease_number = ?, hall_name = ? , hall_number = ?, room_number = ?, student_name = ?, occupancy_status = ?, cleaning_status = ? WHERE hall_name = ? and hall_number = ? and room_number = ?" , (leaseNum.get(), HallName.get(), HallNum.get(), RoomNum.get(), StudentName.get(), OccupancyStatus.get(), CleaningStatus.get(),HallName.get(),HallNum.get(),RoomNum.get()))
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Successfully Updated")
        print('data set has a value')
        con.commit()
```

'''

heres the terminal output
[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9b0g.png)

Comment: instead of `if data == 'None':` it should be `if data == None:`

Comment: `'None'` is a 5 characters string. It has no relationship with the `None` special value.

Comment: BTW, just because the code belonging to `if` is indented doesn't mean that `if` starts a loop.

Comment: If the SELECT statement returns only one record, but you have called `fetchone()` twice, then the second call will get nothing.

Comment: @acw1668 it worked! thank you so much bro.

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating `None` as a String and not as its literal.
You need to remove the quotes around 'None' and use:

`if data is None:`
or even
`if data:`

Comment: Comparison with the `None` singleton should be made with `is`: `if data is None:`.

Comment: i tried that, it just goes the other way. instead of the second message being printed, its the first message being printed. even when theres values inn the data set the first message is being printed.

Comment: Does this make more sense (and work)?
`if data: #perform update else: #print error`

Comment: @Lawrence Bird the solution was this "If the SELECT statement returns only one record, but you have called fetchone() twice, then the second call will get nothing.- acw1668".... i had 2 fetchone()